# How to limit number of connections per vhost in apache2?

Tags: apache2, limit, connection, vhosts

Is there a way to limit number of connections per vhost in apache2?

MaxClients is global per apache instance. And I want to limit number of clients per vhost, so 1 specific vhost wouldn't be able to take all available connections.

Please advise.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can only do this with 3rd-party modules.  For this you can use:

- mod_bw (also known as 'bwmod' from http://bwmod.sourceforge.net)
- mod_vhost_limit
- mod_slotlimit (appears to be somewhat deprecated/abandoned)